# How to query MongoDB from PHP using '$or' or '$and' clause?

Tags: mongodb, php-7.1

I want to get data from mongodb by using MongoDB PHP7.1 Driver with the help of `$or` or `$and` clause in filter. I have tried to construct query to do the same but that didn't work.

Here is my sample code here:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

try {
   $filter = [
        '$or'  => [
          'age' => [ '$gt' => 40],
          'name' => 'abc'
        ]
      ];
   $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);

   $rows = $manager->executeQuery("test.users", $query);


   foreach ($rows as $key => $val) {
      print_r($val);
   }
} catch(MongoDB\Driver\Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
   exit;
}
```

The above code gives me below error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionException: $or must 
be an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\local\demo.php:50 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\local\demo.php(50): MongoDB\Driver\Manager-
>executeQuery('test.users', Object(MongoDB\Driver\Query)) #1 {main} thrown 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\local\demo.php on line 50
```

Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You will need a second expression for $or. Try `$filter = [
        'name' => 'abc',
        '$or'  => [[
          'age' => [ '$gt' => 40]
        ], second expression goes here]
      ];`

Comment: @Veeram thank you it's worked. I had forgot to add that internal array bracket to every condition.

Comment: @Veeram -- many thanks! worked for `$and` the same.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to answer from @Veeram:  Had this as my filter, which did not work:

```
$filter  = [
    '$and' =>
        ['date' => ['$gte' => $start_date]],
        ['date' => ['$lte' => $end_date]]
];
```

added the extra `[]` as @Veeram suggested.  This configuration works for `$and`:

```
$filter  = [
    '$and' => [
        ['date' => ['$gte' => $start_date]],
        ['date' => ['$lte' => $end_date]]
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this also

```
$result=$collections->
find(array('$and=>array(array('date'=>array('$gte'=>$start_date)
),array('date'=>array('$lte'=>$end_date))));
```